# Rally python api - Adding a Tag to an entity?

Tags: python, rally, pyral

I wanted to use pyral to add tags to defects
and I couldn't figure out how to do it

```python
info = dict(test_id="ABC", platform="AAA")
tag1 = rally.create('Tag', dict(Name=info['test_id']))
tag2 = rally.create('Tag', dict(Name=info['platform']))
```

what's next ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found an answer here: 
[how to tag a defect using rally Javascript API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322010/how-to-tag-a-defect-using-rally-javascript-api)

anyhow adding it to documentation might help:

```
tag1 = rally.create('Tag', dict(Name=info['test_id']))
tag2 = rally.create('Tag', dict(Name=info['platform']))

tags = [ dict(_ref=tag1.ref), dict(_ref=tag2.ref)]

defect = { "Tags" : tags }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Glad to be of service :)

Comment: Note that to add a tag in an existing item you can use `rally.addCollectionItems(workitem, [tag])` as mentionned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49826345/1603480